# Checking for null array element in advance

Tags: c#, arrays, null

If I am checking the contents of an array using:

```
boardArray[xIn][yIn]
```

and I am expecting there to be an element, how do I check if there is no element / object there in advance? Really silly question with an obvious answer I know.

I am trying to debug my code, which is expecting something to be in here. I want to pre-check it and report as the program is running rather than have it crash.

Comment: `if(boardArray[xIn][yIn] == null) { ... }`?

Comment: Which is it that might be null, `boardArray`, `boardArray[xIn]`, or `boardArray[xIn][yIn]`? Or some combination of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(boardArray[xIn][yIn] == null)
//Skip it, do something, print it, whatever you gotta do
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to start with something you haven't asked, but which may be relevant to your problem:

I would suggest using a [multidimensional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) array, rather than a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). For example:

```
BoardSquare[,] boardArray = new BoardSquare[8, 8];
```

Most likely you're dealing with a rectangular board, so you have no need for [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

The reason I'm telling this, is because it makes checking for `null` a bit easier. Using a jagged array, any of these could be `null`:

- `boardArray`
- `boardArray[xIn]`
- `boardArray[xIn][yIn]`

Using a two-dimensional array, there are just two possibilities:

- `boardArray`
- `boardArray[xIn, yIn]`

Thus, the check becomes a bit easier:

```
if (boardArray != null && boardArray[xIn, yIn] != null)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

It may be perfectly valid to assume `boardArray` is not null and skip this check, if it can be proven from the initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do anything with nulls,

```
if(!(boardArray[xIn][yIn]==null)) {

// Your operations here 

}
```

You can handle how nulls are treated in the else part, it could be optional

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answers (which are correct) you want to check for nulls on any any level of the array object that might be null.

depending on how you do the checking and needing the info you could just do this

```
if (boardArray != null && boardArray[xIn] != null && boardArray[xIn][yIn] != null){
    // all is good, do what must be done here
}
```

if you're looping through them you could use linq to remove the null items in the loop.  It would be something like this (I dont have the IDE open in front of me so the syntax may be off a bit.  Forgive me.

```
foreach(var instance in boardArray[xIn].Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x).ToList()){
    // instance is the not nulled value.
}
```

I brought up the linq idea to show there are multiple ways of doing what you want to do, depending on the circumstances.

Good luck and happy coding